# Getting a SUM of DateTime differences of a joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables, one stored clocking in times and the other stores breaks taken between the ClockInLogs.TimeIn and TimeOut. There is always going to be more than 1 break for each clockintime.

```
ClockInLogs - 
ID - int
TimeIn - DateTime
TimeOut - DateTime


Breaks - 
CID - Int (joined to ClockInLogs.ID)
TimeIn - DateTime
TimeOut - DateTime
```

In my SQL query, I need to retrieve the total number of hours in the breaks column for each Clock In. So far I have -

```
SELECT
    C.ID,
    C.ClockDateTimeIn as 'Date',
    DATENAME(dw, C.ClockDateTimeIn) as 'DayOfWeek',
    C.UserID,
    C.ClockDateTimeIn as 'ClockInTime',
    C.ClockDateTimeOut as 'ClockOutTime',
    DATEDIFF(minute, ClockDateTimeIn, ClockDateTimeOut) as 'Att'
FROM clockinlogs C
INNER JOIN breaks b on C.ID = b.CID
INNER JOIN Users u on C.UserID = u.ID
```

The next column needed is a total number of hours within the breaks. Basically, for each Break.TimeIn and Break.TimeOut, work out the difference in hours, then add each break up.

I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this works:

```
    SELECT C.ID
           ,C.ClockDateTimeIn as 'Date' 
           ,DATENAME(dw, C.ClockDateTimeIn) as 'DayOfWeek'
           ,C.UserID
           ,C.ClockDateTimeIn as 'ClockInTime'
           ,C.ClockDateTimeOut as 'ClockOutTime'
           ,SUM(convert(time,(b.TimeOut - b.TimeIn))) Att_time
           ,SUM(DATEDIFF(MI, ClockDateTimeIn, ClockDateTimeOut)) Att_minute
           ,SUM(DATEDIFF(HH, ClockDateTimeIn, ClockDateTimeOut)) Att_hour
      FROM clockinlogs C
      JOIN breaks b 
        ON C.ID = b.CID
      JOIN Users u 
        ON CID=ID
  GROUP BY C.ID
           ,C.UserID
           ,C.ClockDateTimeIn
           ,C.ClockDateTimeOut
```

Att_time converts the brekatime to datatype time

Why do You join to Users? To retrieve a name?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your last inner join in that you're not using any fields from the users table in your query unless of course you're trying to filter out clockinlogs for users that don't exist in the users table but is that a possibility? If not it's just adding overhead to your query that isn't needed.

Anyway, I'm no SQL expert by any means and I can probably say this isn't the most efficient query but I imagine this may work, try plugging it in as the last column in your query...

```
(SELECT
    SUM(break)
 FROM (SELECT
           DATEDIFF(minute, BreakTimeIn, BreakTimeOut) AS break
       FROM Breaks
       WHERE CID = C.ID)
 ) AS 'breaks'
```

Your whole query should look like this:

```
SELECT
    C.ID,
    C.ClockDateTimeIn as 'Date',
    DATENAME(dw, C.ClockDateTimeIn) as 'DayOfWeek',
    C.UserID,
    C.ClockDateTimeIn as 'ClockInTime',
    C.ClockDateTimeOut as 'ClockOutTime',
    DATEDIFF(minute, ClockDateTimeIn, ClockDateTimeOut) as 'Att',
    (SELECT
        SUM(break)
     FROM (SELECT
               DATEDIFF(minute, BreakTimeIn, BreakTimeOut) AS break
           FROM Breaks
           WHERE CID = C.ID)
     ) AS 'breaks'
FROM clockinlogs C
INNER JOIN breaks b on C.ID = b.CID
```